# Where to put VueJS components common across the application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

In my `nuxtjs` application, I have few features that are used across the application viz *Login/Signup dialog*, a *snackbar* to show alerts etc. Since, I want these features on every page and `v-app-bar` component is already added to all the pages. I have included the components for these features inside `v-app-bar` component.

```html
<template>
  <v-app-bar app id="app-bar">
    <LoginJoinDialog />
    <AlertSnackbar />

    <!-- Code for App bar -->

  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

But I am not happy with this approach for following reasons

1. I know these common components does not belong to the `v-app-bar` component. And just for the sake of DRY and maintenance headaches I have included them. So from design perspective this is not very intuitive.
2. Secondly, What if in future I have pages that do not have a `v-app-bar` component. In that case I will be repeating code for these common components anyway. So, the pain of maintaining the code at multiple places will still be there.

Considering the above points, I am looking for a more elegant approach than what I have implemented. If there is a `vuejs` recommendation on this, even better. What suggestions do you have for component structuring for these common features?

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive what you are looking for using layouts. What you need to do is make `layouts` folder inside `src` directory. And then you can create as many 
 layout components(*.vue files) and use them as you like.

For an example, this is **default.vue** component inside `layouts` folder:

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <!-- Your app bar component -->
    <v-app-bar app id="app-bar">
      <LoginJoinDialog />
      <AlertSnackbar />
      <!-- Code for App bar -->
    </v-app-bar>

    <!-- Page Content (This tag will automatically embed the page content into layouts)-->
    <nuxt />

  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

Now, on your `pages` folder, you can add **index.vue** file where you can reference the default layout, as a property in this manner: `layout: 'default'`

The index.vue file should look something like this:

```html
<template>
  <!-- page content goes here -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HomePage',
  layout: 'default',
};
</script>
```

I also have created an [example project in nuxt](https://github.com/vectrobyte/nuxt-antail) with layouts.

For a working prototype of the project: [Visit this link](https://nuxt-antail.firebaseapp.com/).

I hope it helps to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [global component registration trick by Chris Fritz](https://youtu.be/7lpemgMhi0k?t=367). You just to need to modify it a bit so it's more fitting for a nuxt.js app. So you can create a `base` folder under your `components` folder and keep all these shared components there. Then create a new plugin and change the path to your `@/components/base` folder and modify the regex so it grabs all the files, no matter what the name is:

*globalComponents.js*

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import upperFirst from 'lodash/upperFirst'
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase'

export default () => {
  const requireComponent = require.context(
    '@/components/base', false, /[\w-]+\.vue$/
  )

  requireComponent.keys().forEach(fileName => {
    const componentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)

    const componentName = upperFirst(
      camelCase(fileName.replace(/^\.\/(.*)\.\w+$/, '$1'))
    )

    Vue.component(componentName, componentConfig.default || componentConfig)
  })
}
```

*nuxt.config.js*

```js
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/globalComponents.js'
],
```